# Does the existence of linker and loader not depend on operating systems such as Linux?

Tags: linker, load, assembly

Does the existence of linker (for performing linking following compilation) and loader (for executing an executable file) not depend on operating systems such as Linux? (I had though of  linker and loader in Linux as either provided by the OS or software just like other application programs. Now I think they are very special and different. They might be the same, regardless of which OS is installed.)

Do linker and loader exist at machine language i.e. ISA level? (At that level, there is no OS.)  Or assembly language level?

Is it correct to think of an OS as a programming library (libraries), from programming software's perspective?

Thanks.

I want to know where to fit linker and loader into levels/layers of a computer system.

For layers/levels of a computer system, see Nisan's The Elements of Computer Systems:

[image]

For linking and loading, see [Computer Systems: A Programmers' Perspective](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/ch7-preview.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

> Does the existence of linker (for performing linking following compilation) and loader (for executing an executable file) not depend on operating systems such as Linux? (I had though of linker and loader in Linux as either provided by the OS or software just like other application programs. Now I think they are very special and different.)

The linker and loader have specific purposes, like any other application. They are important for building static programs and building and loading dynamic programs, but they are “normal” applications (or libraries, in the case of the run-time loader) — *i.e.* while they are complex, they arguably don’t rely on special support from the operating system.

It is thus possible to link programs for one operating system on another (*e.g.* build Windows programs on Linux, or vice versa), and load dynamically-linked programs built for one system on another (see Wine). The main requirements placed on the operating system are that it provide some way of loading new executable content (*i.e.* allow a running program to add executable memory to itself), and that it allow enough control over the virtual address space to satisfy the program’s requirements (in particular, base addresses for loading executables and libraries).

> Do linker and loader exist at machine language i.e. ISA level? (At that level, there is no OS.) Or assembly language level?

I’m not sure what led to these questions, but linkers operate on symbols and addresses. They work with object files which contain tables of imported and exported symbols, and relocation entries where values calculated by the linker are filled in.

> Is it correct to think of an OS as a programming library (libraries)?

That’s very limiting. An operating system provides some services to applications running on it, but it does much more than that, even in the case of really simple operating systems (8-bit micros, MS-DOS etc.); for example, it handles hardware interrupts, schedules processes (for multi-tasking systems), controls access permissions (for multi-user systems with access control)...

I get the impression the diagram you’re referring to is more useful as a book map than as a way of understanding computer architecture.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is it correct that binary files which a linker works on have specific OSes intended for  the files to be used?  So  in that sense, is a linker OS-specific? (2) "It is thus possible to link programs for one operating system on another (e.g. build Windows programs on Linux, or vice versa), and load dynamically-linked programs built for one system on another (see Wine)." Do you mean a linker, which works on binary files intended for specific OS, can run on any other different OS?

Comment: (3) "The main requirements placed on the operating system are that it provide some way of loading new executable content (i.e. allow a running program to add executable memory to itself)". What does "allow a running program to add executable memory to itself" i.e. your definition of "loading new executable content", mean? Do you mean a running program dynamically allocating memory by `malloc()`?

Comment: (1) Not necessarily, some linkers (*e.g.* binutils’ `ld`) can work with files targeting many different architectures and operating systems. Even specific linkers are generally not OS-specific but rather platform-specific. (2) I don’t understand the question. (3) Yes, or `mmap`, but the resulting memory must be executable (some platforms restrict what can allocate executable memory).

Comment: (3) Or do you mean a process can call execve() to load an executable into its address space, by  "loading new executable content", and allow a running program to add executable memory to itself"?

Comment: (3) No, I’m referring to the fact that the dynamic loader and `libdl.so` need to be able to load libraries into memory and map their executable segments appropriately.

Comment: For comment-question (2): The linker performs operations on pieces of data loaded from files, with some specific rules. Although the data is actually machine language program code, these operations can be done on any system if the rules are known. Nothing in the linking process inherently requires the code to be for the system the linker is actually running on, although that is the most common case.  A particular linker only runs on one system architecture, but it may be capable of handling programs of many architectures, for cross-compiling, emulation, forensics or any other purposes.